# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments while executing jobs in parallel

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a monorepo and i am trying to make them run in parallel

```
def abc = findJenkinsfileToRun(modifiedFiles)
parallel {
  for (file in abc) {
    println("Building ${file.toString()}")
    load "${file.toString()}/Jenkinsfile"
  }
}
```

This results in the following

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@b7ccdc
```

can anyone help how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `parallel` keyword correctly, it should receive a map of branch names as keys and execution code (closure) as values. See the [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#parallel-execute-in-parallel).

So in your case you should use something like:

```
def abc = findJenkinsfileToRun(modifiedFiles)
parallel abc.collectEntries { file ->
   ["Building ${file.toString()}" : {
       // The code to run in parallel
       println("Building ${file.toString()}")
       load "${file.toString()}/Jenkinsfile"
   }]
}
```